# Suggestion Regarding Template Engines

Tags: c#, list, loops, conditional-statements, template-engine

I am looking for the template Engines that will cover the loops/lists and conditional(C#).
I searched regarding that and found a few like handlebars and fluids.

So, looking for the best template engines available also with some examples that how we can use that.

Please give your valuable suggestions waiting for your response.

TIA

Comment: Any update on this

Comment: This is a very broad question, you need to specify the framework you're using.For example: ASP.NET has Razor that does just fine regarding looping.

Comment: @Gintas :We need it .net core application